# What is the rules for comparison (< and >) of different types?

Tags: javascript, operators

For `<` operator, it seems very easy to understand when it applies to two strings, two numbers and two booleans.

My question has two parts:

**What is the rule when we use it to compare two objects?**

It seems that I cannot write `{} < {}`, but the following code generate `false`.

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
console.log(a < b); //false
```

**What is the rule when we use it to compare two different type?**

```
true < "" //false
true > "" //true
10 < true //false
10 < "" //false
```

I don't know why the results are like these. I found [an article on comparison in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) but there is no detail.

BTW, I have no question on how `==` and `===` work.

Comment: You should take a look at the Rhino book, JavaScript: The Definitive Guide (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do). This has a great explanation of type conversion and comparison in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the rule when we use it to compare two objects?

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Comparison):

> When comparing variables which are objects they are considered to be
>   different if their objects are not the same object, even if the values
>   of them are the same, so:

```
var obj1 = {a: 1};
var obj2 = {a: 1};
var obj3 = obj1;
alert(obj1 == obj2);   //false
alert(obj3 == obj1);   //true
```

---

> What is the rule when we use it to compare two different type?

It is explained in the article you posted, from which I quote:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a
>   number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if
>   possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is
>   converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then
>   JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands
>   refer to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of detail information in that article:

If the two operands are **not of the same type**, JavaScript converts the operands, then applies strict comparison.

1. If either operand is a **number or a boolean**, the operands **are
   converted to numbers if possible**.
2. Else if either operand is a **string**, the string operand **is
   converted to a number if possible**.
3. If both operands are **objects**, then JavaScript **compares internal
   references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in
   memory**.

So, for numbers, boolean and string:

```
false == 0 == ""
true == 1 == "1" != "any other string (including empty)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the rule when we use it to compare two objects?

For `<` and `>` (and `<=` and `>=`) comparisons, the JavaScript engine calls `valueOf` or `toString` method on the object, if available, to check for greater/lesser. In this example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
console.log(a < b);
```

JavaScript tests the following condition and returns false:

```
"[object Object]" < "[object Object]" // false
```

> What is the rule when we use it to compare two different type?

The rules are same [as those used for **`==`** operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

Objects are converted to strings before comparison.